# Cell with 2 options and I want to add a third

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, cells, data-validation

So I have this excel file where when I select a particular cell a little box with an upside down triangle appears to the right of the cell.

When I click on this there is a small list of options to select, **`"Monday"`** and **`"Thursday"`** and whatever option I choose the cell will be filled with that text.

So my question is, how do I add a third option? So if I want to add **`"Friday"`** to that list of options how do I go about it.

Thanks!

Also when I click Macros or go into VBA there are no macros shown so I am assuming this spreadsheet is using none.

Comment: Oh sorry I found it. Just need to use Data Validation in the Data tab

Comment: Why not add that as an answer, and fill it out with a description of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To create or add data validation, Select cell, then go to Data tab, click Data Validation

[image]

See [Apply data validation to cells](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-data-validation-to-cells-c743a24a-bc48-41f1-bd92-95b6aeeb73c9#bm4)